# Creating an NSObject to store data

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface, nsobject

I am trying to create an object in the following way:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Song : NSObject{
    NSString *songID;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *artist:
    NSString *album;
    NSString *length:
    NSString *votes;   
}
@end
```

I get the error `Unexpected interface name 'NSString': expected expression`

Could somebody also explain what the difference between adding variables after the interface with a {}?   Some code I see uses the brackets others don't (they just the @property method).  Or any link to documentation would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using ":" instead of ";" after `artist` and `length`.